# Stash - How to nest within a nested Matrix set_list?

Tags: stash

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="my_entries" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="clients" limit="5"}

        {stash:entry_title}{title}{/stash:entry_title}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="related_entries_{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}

            {!-- this is a matrix tag pair --}
            {contact_docs}
                {stash:related_title}{mx_doc_title}{/stash:related_title}
            {/contact_docs}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}    

    {/exp:channel:entries}  
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="my_entries"}

    Entry title: {entry_title}

    Related:
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="related_entries_{entry_id}"}
        {related_title}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

---

`{contact_docs}` have `{mx_doc_title}` field.
Let say if there is 1 more custom field, `{type}`, and it can be a multiple item.
How to I store it and retrieve it?

Comment: What type of field is `{type}` and where is it?

Comment: let say the {type} is Multi-Select Options Checkboxs under the {related_title}.

{exp:stash:get_list:nested name="related_entries_{entry_id}"}
        {related_title}
        {type} <---- HERE
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}